# Generic Javascript function that takes Javascript predefined functions as parameter and returns the respective outputs?

Tags: javascript

For example we have functions like substring(), slice(), concat() etc. -Consider most or all String Manipulation functions in Javascript. Is it possible to write a generic function that takes these predefined function along with some arguments and return the values dynamically?

```
function genericJS(fnName, Args) {
....... Does something
return value; 
}
```

I want to be able to call `genericJs('slice',['1','5'],'hello world')(it should return 'ello') or genericJs('substring',[':',','],'hi:world,xyz')(it should return 'world')` etc.

Is this possible? Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You could wrap your generic around `switch case` statements then use the generic strings as the conditions.

Comment: What's the expected output of `genericJs('slice', ['1', '5'])`?

Comment: Hi @nem035, edited the question to show the output i am expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ideas but here's one:

```js
function genericJS1(methodName, args) {
  return String
    .prototype[methodName]
    .apply(
      args[0],
      args.slice(1)
    )
}

console.log(genericJS1('split', ['this:is:an:example', ':']))
```

Another one could be to return a partially applied function:

```js
function genericJS1(methodName, args) {
  return (str) => 
    String
      .prototype[methodName]
      .apply(
        str,
        args
      )
}

const splitOnColon = genericJS1('split', [':'])

console.log(splitOnColon('this:is:an:example'))
```

Comment: Thank you nem035. This is a nice approach.